# JUnit: Test should pass if it hangs for a certain amount of time

Tags: java, junit

I found code that will cause a test to *fail* if it runs for longer than `timeout` ms. What if I want it to pass? I have a function that I expect will hang forever. If it hangs for long enough, say 10000 ms, then I assume that it's hanging forever and the test should pass.

```
@Test(timeout=10000) public void test() {
   while(true)
}
```

Comment: What would your test confirm other than that the method never returns?

Comment: I want to test that querying a closed connection will hang forever. (The code retries establishing the connection forever).

Comment: There is a nice concept called **fail fast**. When things are broken, you want to come back as soon as possible. Anything else just **increases** your problems.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your test. A test that asserts a method doesn't return in a certain amount of time does just that. Unless you're asserting something else the method could be doing anything (or nothing) for all you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you want to `test that querying a closed connection will hang forever. (The code retries establishing the connection forever)`
So you want to hang your program forever, everytime someone tries to query closed connection?

I would better throw exception when connection is closed.

Comment: My code is a wrapper around an open source library. I believe this is the behavior in the library, I can't change it.

Comment: I would write facade for that library and prevent to query closed connections via e.g. throwing exceptions. Then I would start to seach such  a library that won't hung forever...

Comment: BTW, you can stop opening connection after e.g. 5000ms and then you can verify that method ends with more than 5000s using Mockito:
`Mocktio.verify(object,Mockito.timeout(6000)).equals(null);`

Comment: Thanks for your help staszek. It turns out I was wrong about the connection hanging forever. It actually retries to connect every 30 seconds, for up to 15 minutes. (I thought it was hanging forever because I never waited 15 minutes). I was able to override the settings so that it timed out more quickly.